# google map api Draggable directions With Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, laravel-5, google-maps-markers

I know that there is a cool lib called **Googlmapper** for using googleMapApi in laravel,
 but I actually didn't use it before , and I don't know if it has the drag direction option like in google api direction draggable [googleMapApi direction draggable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable) ,
 
I need this , as I'm developing an app in which the admin will be able to **draw the directions for buses drivers** 
so that they able to know where they stop to pick up people .
the driver will do that as he will have an android app so that he can see the direction that the admin made .
I need for the web app for the admin ,
 the android app is not my responsibility 
so I want to know how to make Direction Draggable google map api IN Laravel .
 
what Lib to use How to use them ,is there any tutorials for that or books
 any thing will be great